# Failed to resolve: firebase-ads:15.0.1:15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I wanted to monetize my app using admob. [image: Using the firebase in assistant tab]

When i used the admob option available in firebase it asked me to add the following dependency `'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1:15.0.0'` 
but after the gradle build it gave me this error `Failed to resolve: firebase-ads-15.0.0` so i used `'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:12.0.1'` which works great but with this one i can't see the ads. These are my dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:12.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1:15.0.0'
}
```

This is my project level gradle file

```
 buildscript {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
 }

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase **core** and **ads** compile version should same 
Try this version **16.0.4**

It looks like this :

`implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4`

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.4'`

Comment: I have mentioned it that this fix doesn't work as ads don't display

Comment: @AnshulSharma Check on another device also

Comment: the add admob dependency in firebase (screenshot) gets disabled when the version is changed to 12.0.1

Comment: Don't check on emulator, if you publish an on PlayStore then its take a time  to visible ads on real devices

Comment: `mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);`

Comment: isn't the above supposed to show me ads on emulator? According to you, the ads will display once it is published on play store right?

Comment: the listener methods are never used so they dont work

Answer (score 0):

change line :

```
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1:15.0.0'
```

to

```
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
```

Comment: Error: Type com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzcl is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.zzc`.